Merge isnt smooth
There are two parts that I want to combine, but when switching to the subdivisions surface modifier, a square joint is formed.
On one side and on the other, there were a different number of edges, which is why some of them had to be dissolved and the edge was drawn into quadrilaterals. I also tried to convert these borders to a circle, and the joint itself, too, but nothing works.
The most interesting thing is that with the other two parts, everything went perfectly, there was no such problem.
(this is my very first experience just straight after donut, pls be kind <3)


Hello, you probably have some inner faces or please share your file

Hello, thanks for your answer, when i saw it for first time i thought the same, but there no inner faces. also idk how to share it here :)
i would be really thankful for any help

Hello, Eri, follow the instructions on https://blend-exchange.com/, and paste the resulting link into your post.. try A select all, M > Merge By Distance ?

"Straight after donut"... a reference only Blenderheads understand. ;-) Nice. (Welcome to the site!)

@Mentalist Thanks, I appreciate that <3
Before searching tutorials on youtube i was curios why there are so many different and even more identical donuts on the first search site for download 3d model, then I understood :D

As you can see you have flipped normals, select all in Edit mode and press ShiftN:


YAAAYYYYY!!! NOW I SEE
Thank you so much <333

@Eri Please accept the answer if this is the solution.

@GordonBrinkmann thanks, i didnt notice this function, just accepted
